# Broke MongoDB schema version 3 but found 1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was following instructions at http://lukaszkups.net/blog/0006_deploying_meteorjs_app_to_own_server_via_ssh/ to configure mongo for use with meteor on my ubuntu 10.04 on EC2, realised my mongo was old (2.4.9) so upgraded it to 2.6.11, that is when the schema version mismatch started, need help to fix it.

```
> db = db.getSiblingDB('admin')
admin

> db.addUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']})
WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead 
2015-10-29T14:15:14.850+0000 Error: couldn't add user: User and role management commands require auth data to have schema version 3 but found 1 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1086

> db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']})
2015-10-29T14:15:34.788+0000 Error: couldn't add user: User and role management commands require auth data to have schema version 3 but found 1 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1086

> db = db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
{ "done" : true, "ok" : 1 }

> db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']})
2015-10-29T14:18:03.809+0000 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'createUser'

> db = db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 3 });
2015-10-29T14:18:32.005+0000 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getSiblingDB'

> db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});
2015-10-29T14:19:34.554+0000 TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

>  db = db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
2015-10-29T14:20:06.042+0000 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getSiblingDB'

> db = db.getSiblingDB('admin')
2015-10-29T14:20:20.370+0000 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getSiblingDB'

> db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});
2015-10-29T14:23:33.677+0000 TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

> use admin
2015-10-29T14:24:14.413+0000 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getMongo' at src/mongo/shell/utils.js:533

> version
function version() { [native code] }

> db = db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});
2015-10-29T14:52:19.697+0000 TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
>
```

Now mongodb would not start.

```
ubuntu$ sudo service mongodb restart
stop: Unknown instance:
mongodb stop/waiting
ubuntu$ sudo service mongodb start
mongodb stop/waiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you are losing DB scope with 4th command.
5th command should be:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']})
```

*db = db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']}) won't set the correct reference*

Comment: I tried that,    ' > db = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
    admin
    > db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase']})
    2015-10-29T15:28:23.737+0000 Error: couldn't add user: User "admin@admin" already exists at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1086'

Comment: Now you could continue upgrading then... `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 3 });` should be the next command (don't reassign it to db)

Comment: This means you're all set!

Comment: mongodb wont start continues to be in stop/waiting

Comment: continue with codes ... next in the list seems to be `db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});`

Comment: WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: I solved running just:

    $ service mongod restart

Comment: @DeepakArora glad it worked, and glad you are using MongoDB. Good luck!